# How to control an allocated tuner device from the python module

Tags: redhawksdr

I have a Redhawk node running on a Raspberry Pi with an RTL2832U tuner. I can allocate the tuner from a waveform in the IDE and change the tuner settings from the IDE using the properties view. My question is how can I change the *allocated* tuner settings from python using the redhawk python module? Appendix F.4 of the Redhawk manual describes this control being performed through a Tuner port (DigitalTuner_in) on the device and then lists a number of Tuner Control Functions. How do I call these functions? (from Python - or any other way).

Answer (score 0):

This was written a while ago so there may be some new utilities to simplify the process but should still be valid example.
https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/FrontEndController

Comment: Thanks Youssef. I'll give it a try.